# How to get the raw number of bytes that a given PID is using from the Linux terminal regardless of distro?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to CLI-get the number of bytes, such as `123456`, corresponding to the RAM usage of a given process based on its PID. It must work without any special software and on all Linux distros. No formatting or "kB" or extra information. Just an integer value as output.

As usual, the Web is full of articles with lots of noise but no actual useful information.

Comment: what have you tried that does not work?

Comment: Huh? I'm asking how to do it. I can't try it before I have it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We expect questions to show some basic research effort (see [ask]). The lack of research effort in your question may be the reason somebody voted down. "Gimme command or script, my requirements are …" without research hardly ever meets a warm reception. The first comment is like "show us your research effort", totally normal reaction in such cases, an attempt to help you improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these methods:

```bsh
# process id
pid=$$
# memory page size
psz=$(grep -m1 KernelPageSize /proc/$pid/smaps |tr -d -c [0-9])
# assume by “RAM usage” OP wants “resident size”
printf '
1. with “ps” command    : %d
2. from /proc/pid/status: %d
3. from /proc/pid/statm : %d
4. from /proc/pid/stat  : %d
' $( ps -p $pid ho rsz ) \
  $( grep -m1 VmRSS /proc/$pid/status |tr -d -c [0-9] ) \
  $( read -a s < /proc/$pid/statm; echo $(( ${s[1]} * $psz )) ) \
  $( read -a s < /proc/$pid/stat; echo $(( ${s[23]} * $psz )) )
```

```
1. with “ps” command    : 12160
2. from /proc/pid/status: 12160
3. from /proc/pid/statm : 12160
4. from /proc/pid/stat  : 12160
```

※ For `/proc` filesystem refer to [linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html)

※ For `ps` command check [its manual](https://fossies.org/linux/procps-ng/ps/ps.1)

Comment: This doesn't look like a single command to me. In fact, I don't understand it at all.